# IPv6 Static Address Allocation

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6

I run a few web servers and would like to get a block of ipv6 addresses that i can use on these servers that are static, my ISP do not offer them.

I use Ubuntu Servers.

Any information would be of help.

Dave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find an ISP that offers IPv6 connectivity.

If that's not an option right now, and you have a static IPv4 address, then you already have a block of static IPv6 addresses to play with, through the magic of [6to4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6to4). 6to4 is only meant to be a temporary IPv4 to IPv6 transition method, not a permanent solution. I wouldn't try to host a site with any kind of serious traffic over 6to4, but as a simple way to test the IPv6 waters, [it may be worth checking out](http://6to4.version6.net/?lang=en_GB).

Comment: 6to4 is no longer recommended, due to bad performance and instability. That doesn't mean it's not an option, but you'll get better results by using a 6in4 tunnel from a tunnelbroker such as [SixXS](http://www.sixxs.net/) or [Hurricane Electric](http://tunnelbroker.net/). They're both free.

Comment: @Martijn Heemels: Are you speaking from personal experience with 6to4? The kind of performance and stability you get from 6to4 is likely strongly related to how well your ISP maintains its routes to its 6to4 gateway.

Comment: Not personal experience, just hearsay: 1. You don't get to choose the quality and availability of your 6to4 relay, since you're dependant on anycast routing. 2. There's the probability of asymmetric routing, which may lead to problems. Indeed strongly related to the quality of your ISP. 6to4 is definitely an option, but I'd recommend a 6in4 tunnel instead.

Comment: @Martijn Heemels: Good points. I do agree that a 6in4 tunnel is going to be a superior solution in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

Who do you get your IPv4 addresses from now? have you asked them?

Comment: He does say that his ISP doesn't do IPv6, I'm assuming that his ISP currently does his IPv4 addresses.